# Get user from user meta_value array in WordPress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

i need help with WordPress to get user use `get_user();`
If user meta_value not array i can handle it, but now user meta_value is array.

```
$array_user_meta = array(
    'user_id' => 100,
    'user_facebook_id' => 58977667867887,
);

$wp_users = get_users(array(
    'meta_key'     => 'user_biodata',
    'meta_value'   => 'how to access user_facebook_id,
    'number'       => 1,
    'count_total'  => false,
    'fields'       => 'id',
));
```

Thank you.,

=====================

**Edited;**

The `$array_user_meta` only sample, not actual array to get value `'user_facebook_id'`, so can't get value like `$array_user_meta['user_facebook_id'];`

I case, this use in facebook user login auth., so i want if user already registered they automatic login.

Now, the `user_facebook_id` stored as array in `user_biodata`. so can't passed meta_key (user_biodata) and meta_value (facebook_id) directly:

```
$wp_users = get_users(array(
    'meta_key'     => 'user_biodata',
    'meta_value'   => 'can't passed user_facebook_id because stored in array',
    'number'       => 1,
    'count_total'  => false,
    'fields'       => 'id',
));
```

Comment: I'm even more confused now after your update...

Answer (score 0):

You can access the facebook ID using the associative array key.

```
<?php
$user_facebook_id = $array_user_meta['user_facebook_id'];
```

*Referencing: [http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php_)*

Answer (score 0):

Pass the array value to the function like this

```
$array_user_meta = array(
    'user_id' => 100,
    'user_facebook_id' => 58977667867887,
);

$wp_users = get_users(array(
    'meta_key'     => 'user_biodata',
    'meta_value'   => $array_user_meta['user_facebook_id'],
    'number'       => 1,
    'count_total'  => false,
    'fields'       => 'id',
));
```

Answer (score 0):

use below function for get user meta value.

```
<?php
    /*$array_user_meta = array(
        'user_id' => 100,
        'user_facebook_id' => 58977667867887,
    );*/

  $all_meta_for_user_array = get_user_meta( 100 ); // user id
 foreach($all_meta_for_user_array as $all_meta_for_user_value)
 {
     $user_facebook_id = $all_meta_for_user_value['user_facebook_id'];
     $wp_users = get_users(array(
        'meta_key'     => 'user_biodata',
        'meta_value'   => $user_facebook_id,
        'number'       => 1,
        'count_total'  => false,
        'fields'       => 'id',
    ));
 }
?>
```